# Moggaliputta-tissa Kathavatthu

Tags: middle-way, nagarjuna

Anyone knows where I can find an english translation of Moggaliputta’s work “Kathavatthu” (The Points of Controversy) where he somehow “saved” the Buddha’s message of the middle way contained in the Dhammacakkappavattana-sutta, which then later has been rejected by Theravada and Mahayana schools but flourished under Nagarjuna?

Answer (score 1):

I found it here :

https://archive.org/details/pointsofcontrove00mogg/mode/2up

the other version online is the transliteration from Sanskrit.